# Java Regex: match all reocurring sequences in a string

Tags: java, regex

I read some of the examples to match all occurrences of a sequence in a string but I am getting some difficulty with this example. I want to match expressions as follows:

```
"test"-a-"test2"-b-"test3" ...//can alternate like this for any number of times
```

When I test my code on the above example it works but when I try for an example such as the following it tells me that the match is successful but I do not want it to be successful.

```
"test"-a-"test2"-b"test3"  //this is successful but I want it to fail
```

The regex I am using is:

```
^ ( ( \ " ( . * ) ? \ " ) * \ \  - ( [ a - z ] ) \ \ - \ " ( . * ) ? \ " ) + $ ;
```

Comment: What is the exact format in general?

Comment: What the pattern of the strings?

Comment: It begins with a string of characters in quotes then followed by a single lowercase letter surrounded by minus signs and must end with a string of characters in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\"[^\"]+?\"-[a-z]-)+\"[^\"]+?\"$");
```

As you said: "It begins with a string of characters in quotes then followed by a single lowercase letter surrounded by minus signs and must end with a string of characters in quotes".

Comment: I tried it above but when i tested it against something like, "test"-a-"test2"b"test3" , it passes

Comment: Ok, it was matching everything from the first quote to the last. Please try the updated regex.

Comment: @laune Thanks, corrected the regex and put it in Java code format for clarity.

Comment: The single `\` preceding the hyphen is confusing. There's no need to escape the hyphen for the regex.

Comment: @laune This is to escape `"` in a Java string.

Comment: I wanted to write "single backslash preceding the hyphen", but I see that this has been fixed. (sorry for the typo).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
    String[] str = new String[] { "\"test\"-a-\"test2\"-b-\"test3\"",
                                  "\"test\"-a-\"test2\"-b\"test3\"", 
                                  "\"test\"-a-\"test2\"b\"test3\"" };

    // quote then one or more lower letter quote - one lower letter - <same pattern till the end>
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\"[a-z]+\"-[a-z]-\"[a-z]+\\d\"-[a-z]-\"[a-z]+\\d\")$");

    for (String s : str) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        System.out.println(s + (m.find() ? " found" : " not found"));
    }
```

output:

```
    "test"-a-"test2"-b-"test3" found
    "test"-a-"test2"-b"test3" not found
    "test"-a-"test2"b"test3" not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use this:

```
String t = ...;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\"[^\"]+?\"(?:-[a-z]-\"[^\"]+?\")+" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( t );
if( m.matches() ){
  // OK
} else {
  // not OK
}
```